# Update input field from controller which serves as a filter provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a input text element in my view:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.$">
```

Which serves as a filter provider for my list:

```
<a ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" href="#">{{item.name}}</a>
```

I use `search.$` because I want to search through all the object properties in `item`.

What I want to do now is to set the input value programmatically from the controller at any time:

```
angular.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
  var query;
  $scope.updateSearchQuery = function () {
     //query is populated form another source, service, http provider...
     $scope.search = query;
});
```

But this new `query` does not show up in the input field (although it filters the list).

I've also tried scope. apply to no avail:

```
...
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.search = query;
});
...
```

**UPDATE**: I've also tried

```
$scope.search.$ = query;
```

Here is a plnk: http://plnkr.co/edit/CwzsrJxU9Kb9AARVcENT?p=preview

What am I missing here?

Comment: $scope.search.$ = query; ?

Comment: $scope.search = {$ : query};

Comment: Forgot to mention that I tried both, but didn't work.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Xpaj4D6zTvs4xE2CxEGh?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `$` as a property name is not really recommended, because angular strips properties that start with `$` internally, when used in functions such as `jsonFilter` and others.

You say you're using a dollar sign variable because you want to filter the array by all properties, but that can be accomplished without having a '$' variable in your search object.

Here's a fixed version of your example:

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/5GfV6r8iqMWYtm1QkiAs?p=preview)</kbd>

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.search = {
    query: ''
  };

  $scope.updateSearchQuery = function (query) {
    $scope.search.query = query;
  }

  $scope.items = [
    {
      id: 'someid',
      name: 'John'
    },
    {
      id: 'someotherid',
      name: 'Smith'
    },
    {
      id: 'anotherid',
      name: 'Patrick'
    }
  ];

});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search.query">
  <button ng-click="search.query=''">Clear</button>
  <a style="display:block" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:{$: search.query}" href="#">
    {{item.id}} | {{item.name}}
  </a>

  <button ng-click="updateSearchQuery('John')">Set Filter to "John"</button>
  <button ng-click="updateSearchQuery('some')">Set Filter to "some"</button>

</body>
```

Btw, `$scope.search.$ = query;` could not work because `$scope.search` was never initialised.